# Autocomplete based on slot inside S4 object

Tags: rstudio

I'm trying to get RStudio column autocomplete to work with a custom S4 class. The class has slots `data` (a `data.frame`) and `version` (`character`), and a `$` method which accesses the data `slot`, e.g.

```
setClass("MyDb", representation(data = "data.frame", version = "character"))

setMethod("$", signature = "MyDb", 
          function(x, name) { return(x@data[[name]]) }
)

db <- new("MyDb", data = mtcars, version = "2.3.1")
```

Using `db$mpg` accesses `db@data$mpg`, as I expect, but using `db$` doesn't bring up any autocomplete options in RStudio.

My approach is modelled after the `sp` package, for which I do see autocomplete options for the `data` slot in a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, e.g.

```
library(sp)  
data("meuse")
coordinates(meuse) <- ~ x + y
meuse$  # brings up autocomplete options for meuse@data slot
```

Is there a particular method or strategy I can use to enable autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by cloning the `sp` library and systematically deleting stuff until the autocomplete stopped working. RStudio autocomplete seems to require a `names` method that gets exported in the package `NAMESPACE`, e.g.

```
# in MyDb.R
names.MyDb <- function(x) names(x@data)

# in NAMESPACE
S3method(names,MyDb)
```